# mat-selection-list doesn't show in mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In creating a mat-autocomplete component that would for allow multiple selections, I wanted to use a mat-selection-list.
This would provide some desired native functionality, like the checkboxes for instance.

The dynamic mat-selectiion-list does not show inside of a mat-autocomplete even when the array 'chartList' is initiated with values.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{ Patient }}</mat-label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Text" matInput formControlName="links" [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-selection-list #selectionList (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"  [disableRipple]="true">

            <mat-list-option *ngFor="let chart of chartList" [value]="chart"
                [checkboxPosition]="'before'" [id]="chart.key">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <span class="col-4 xs-text">{{ chart.name }}</span>
                    <span class="col-3 xs-text">{{chart.additionalData.dateOfBirth | date}}</span>
                    <span class="col-4 xs-text">{{chart.additionalData.city }}</span>
                </div>
            </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

The cdk-panel is shown as a thin dropdown with no content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the [Docs](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) thoroughly I thought perhaps this had something to do with it.

> Each option should be defined by an mat-option tag

However, as I mentioned in the question a mat-selecetion-list was to be used.
Plus it clearly states **should** and not **must be**.

However this was the solution that worked:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{ Patient }}</mat-label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Text" matInput formControlName="links" [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-selection-list #selectionList (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"  [disableRipple]="true">

            <mat-list-option *ngFor="let chart of chartList" [value]="chart"
                [checkboxPosition]="'before'" [id]="chart.key">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <span class="col-4 xs-text">{{ chart.name }}</span>
                    <span class="col-3 xs-text">{{chart.additionalData.dateOfBirth | date}}</span>
                    <span class="col-4 xs-text">{{chart.additionalData.city }}</span>
                </div>
            </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>

     <mat-option [style.display]="'none'"></mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Note the edition of an empty mat-option.

Not sure why it's necessary...